# Edit box/Nodeclipse EditBox plugin not working anymore with Eclipse 4.18.0

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editbox

I am getting the following error with edit box plugin in Eclipse:

> ava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/eclipse/ui/internal/misc/StringMatcher    at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.impl.BoxProviderImpl$Matcher.(BoxProviderImpl.java:176)
> at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.impl.BoxProviderImpl.getMatchers(BoxProviderImpl.java:97)
> at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.impl.BoxProviderImpl.supportsFile(BoxProviderImpl.java:84)
> at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.impl.BoxProviderImpl.supports(BoxProviderImpl.java:79)
> at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.impl.BoxProviderRegistry.getBoxProvider(BoxProviderRegistry.java:153)
> at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.actions.EnableEditBox.decorate(EnableEditBox.java:94)
> at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.actions.EnableEditBox.setVisible(EnableEditBox.java:87)
> at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.actions.EnableEditBox.runCommand(EnableEditBox.java:55)
> at
> pm.eclipse.editbox.actions.EnableEditBox.run(EnableEditBox.java:39)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:239)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:218)
> at
> org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:580)
> at
> org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.lambda$5(ActionContributionItem.java:453)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4209)     at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1037)    at
> org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4026)
> at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3626)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1157)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
> at
> org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
> at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)   at
> org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
> at
> org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:401)
> at
> org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:653)  at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:590)     at
> org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1461)

I don't know how to solve this issue... If someone could give tips it would be great.

Comment: That looks like the plug-in is trying to use an internal Eclipse class, which it is not supposed to do. The internal class has now been removed so the plug-in will not work until it is fixed to use something else. Report this to the authors of the plug-in.

Comment: This is working now.I got an updated jar file from the following link:http://editbox.sourceforge.net/updates